# Advertising Identifier declaration missing? Testflight external testers

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, beta

I've tried to submit my app to the Beta review (Testflight, external testers) and got this mail after submitting.

> Undeclared Use of Advertising Identifier [IDFA]. Your app contains the
>   Advertising Identifier [IDFA] API but you have not indicated its usage
>   on the Prepare for Submission page in iTunes Connect. Click Submit for
>   Review to access the Prepare for Submission page and indicate IDFA
>   usage.

After this the word "invalid" appears beside the upload date in the build section. At the submission process I wasn't able to declare the IDFA, because there were only the cryptography questions. I did this twice now...

What can I do to fix this issue?